# edit mode show a bunch of weird vertices after loading

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I was working on my mesh earlier today and after loading it tonight, I can't work on it anymore. While Object Mode show my mesh as I saved it, Edit Mode does really weird things that I can't even describe, so here are the screenshots: [image: Object Mode] [image: Edit mode]

I probably did something accidentally, but I have no idea what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Shapekey selected, so when you try to edit, you are editing that key. The key itself has most likely been messed up due to changes in model topology or vertex ordering.

If you select the Shapekey called basis, then you will be able to edit the underlying shape.

Comment: Thanks, i probably put a shape key on that mesh by mistake. I deleted it and everything was back to normal. 
=)